# I want to plus the number form string datatype

Tags: c, atoi

I have the following input as string:

```
Num: 12345
```

I would like to print out the sum of digits from the input (1+2+3+4+5 = 15):

```
total:15
```

I tried, but there is a problem with `atoi()` in the `for` loop and I got an error:

> [Error] invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'

How can I fix that or how can I resolve it in an easier way?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <ctype.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 char numstr[100];
 int total = 0;

 main(){
     printf("Num:");
     scanf("%s", numstr);

     for(int i = 0; i < strlen(numstr); i++){
         total += atoi(numstr[i]);
     }
     printf("%d", total);
 }
```

Comment: [read the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subtract the numeric character (in ASCII) by 0x30 (i.e. ASCII character zero '0') to convert the ASCII numeric character to its decimal equivalent.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <ctype.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 char numstr[100];
 int total=0;
 main(){
 printf("Num:");
 scanf("%s",numstr);

 for(int i = 0;i<strlen(numstr);i++){
     total += numstr[i] - 0x30;
 }
 printf("%d",total);
 }
```

The string "12345" will be

```
1 -> 0x31 - 0x30 = 1
2 -> 0x32 - 0x30 = 2
3 -> 0x33 - 0x30 = 3
4 -> 0x34 - 0x30 = 4
5 -> 0x35 - 0x30 = 5
```

Comment: a better version of this would be to subtract `'0'`, since that doesn't rely on the ascii codes for numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the integer value of a digit character by subtracting the zero character from it.

`total += numstr[i] - '0';`

It is because the `0` character has value equal with `48` in decimal (or `0x30` in hexadecimal), `1` character is equal with `49` in decimal, `2` with `50` and so on..

Subtracting the `0` character from itself, results in `0` (decimal). Subtracting the `0` character from character `1` results in `1` (decimal) and so on..

Answer (score 0):

[`atoi()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi) does not do what you think it does.

A possible way to achieve what you want is to use `atoi()`, or better, `strtol()` to convert the user input to integer type, and then use the modulo operaptor to extract each digit and add them.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <ctype.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>


 int main(void){                     //correct signature

     int total=0;                    // no need to be global
     char numstr[100] = {0};         // same
     int ret = -1;

     printf("Num:");
     ret = scanf("%99s",numstr);       
     if (ret != 1){                    // basic sanity check for scanf
         printf("Error in scanning\n");
         exit (-1);
     }

     long int converted = strtol(numstr, NULL, 10);   // convert to integer
     printf("%ld\n\n", converted);

     for (int i = 0; converted; i++){

         total += converted %10;                // add the digit
         converted /= 10;                       // reduce the last added digit
     }

     printf("%d",total);
     return 0;                               // return 0 is implicit for `main()`, anyways
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple! Take the input as string and subtract the character by '0'. This will give you the number at that particular position. See my code below :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char numstr[100];
int total=0;
main(){
printf("Num:");
scanf("%s",numstr);

for(int i = 0;i<strlen(numstr);i++){
 total += (numstr[i]-'0');
}
printf("%d",total);
}
```

Saves the hassle of using atoi() or other functions.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach to your problem could be to replace

```
total += atoi(numstr[i]);
```

with

```
total += numstr[i] - '0';
```

You might want to to check if isdigit(numstr[i]) is true first, for error checking.